# Form does not submit or button submit not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

As far as I know this code must work but I when I coded it it does not work
The problem is that the form does not submit. How can I solve this ? 
I don't even get the value of the checkbox when checked .

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Item Photo</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Stocks</th>
    <th>Date Posted</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</thead>
<tbody>

<form action ="<?php echo base_url()?>Shop/test" method="POST">
    <?php
    $x=1;

    foreach($shop_items as $key)
    {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><input class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="<?php $key->shop_item_id?>"> <?php echo $x;?> </td>
        <td><center><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/items_main/<?php echo $key->shop_item_main_pic;?>"  style = "width:60px;height:50px;"alt=""></center></td>
        <td><?php echo mb_strimwidth($key->shop_item_name, 0, 18,"...");?></td>
        <td style="width:10px;"><center><button><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></button></center></td>
        <td><?php echo date('F,d,Y',strtotime($key->shop_item_date_posted))?></td>
        <td><?php if(!$key->shop_item_sale){ echo number_format($key->shop_item_orig_price);}
        else{ echo "<font color='red'>".number_format(intval($key->shop_item_orig_price-($key->shop_item_orig_price*($key->shop_item_sale/100))))."</font> ";}?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="">Bid </a> | <a href=""> View</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $x+=1; 
    }
    ?>
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>

</form>
</tbody>
```

In the Controller, the structure is like this

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
  if (isset($_POST["cb"])) {
     // Checkbox is checked.
  $cb = $_POST["cb"];
  echo $cb;
} 
else {
     $cb = $_POST["cb"];
     echo $cb;
}
        }
```

Comment: or just the submit button does not work

Comment: a `<form>` should not be children of `<tbody>`. You need to place it inside `<td>` tags. Either that, or place the form outside of the `table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you emit all the PHP you are left with bad HTML:

```
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>Shop/test" method="POST">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="<?php $key->shop_item_id ?>"> <?php echo $x; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
                    <span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete
                </button>
            </form>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

`form` shoul not be a child of `tbody`. Any content in a `table` should be inside `th` or `td` tags. You should place the `form` outside of the `table` and the `button` inside `td` tags:

```
   <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>Shop/test" method="POST">
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <th>ID</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="<?php $key->shop_item_id ?>"> <?php echo $x; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
                            <span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: How can I make the submit button work outside the table?

Comment: If thats the case, place it outside of the table, before the `</form>` tag

Comment: I want my submit button appear on the above the table. Because the process is that I will select the items to be deleted.

Comment: if you want it on top, then place it after the open `<form>` tag

Comment: The form submitted but it doesn't contain anything

Comment: What makes you say that? how are you receiving the request?

Comment: I got 3 checkbox, I checked them all and receive an output of ^^

Comment: ^ comes from the implode controller

Comment: Bro I did it. The last problem is to need replace the button outside the table but the problem when I do that it does not read the check box

Comment: Im glad you figured it out. Thanks.